# can't get data when use multiproc by libnids

Tags: capture, pcap, nic, libnids

I capture tcp stream by using libnids. here is code summary.

```
nids_params.pcap_filter = (char*)filter;
nids_params.multiproc = 0; // i can recieve data when set 0, but drop packet
nids_params.multiproc = 1; // i can't recieve any data when set 1

nids_init();
nids_register_tcp(xxx);
nids_run();
```

When i set nids_params.multiproc = 0 which disable multi thread, i can recvieve data.

but when set to 1, there was no data.

Some met this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get some log from /var/log/libnids.log (default).

Need more information to solve this problem.